# How can we write " in nsstring?

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I have to initialize string as "Rose" including Quotation Mark. How to write " in our string?

Comment: @pt2ph8: Haha, I was wondering why there were no answers here, but as soon as I posted mine and refreshed the page, bang a lot of answers. I think our difference in times was one second or two, though If you check answers by "oldest", I'm the first :-)

Comment: @pt2ph8 Textbook example of a bike shed. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_Law_of_Triviality

Comment: @sidyll: It was exactly one second. ;)

Comment: upvote everyone! (party)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Escape the double quote with \

```
NSString *yourString = @"\"Rose\"";
```

Answer (score 9):

Use the escape character: \

```
NSString *r = @"\"Rose\"";
```

You can find additional information about [Escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) and [String literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal).

Answer (score 8):

Escape it with a backslash:

```
@"\"Rose\""
```

Answer (score 7):

Escape the quotation marks.

Example:

```
NSString *str = @"\"Rose\"";
```

Answer (score 6):

```
NSString *yourString = @"\"Rose\"";
```

Answer (score 1):

In swift 5, you can write with a hashtag :

```
 let raw = #"You can create "raw" strings in Swift 5."#
```

Output :

```
You can create "raw" strings in Swift 5.
```