# How put " to NSString?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I want have src=" character in NSString.

But I can' t do it, becouse " is part of Objective C.

I want do sth like this:

```
NSString * name = [ [NSString alloc] initWithString: @" src=" " ];
```

How i can do this?

Comment: @tipycalFlow escape codes start with a backslash `\ `, not a forward slash `/`. Huge difference.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII My bad...typo...but still a trivial question

Comment: @tipycalFlow: Delete your comment - it is completely wrong.

Comment: @EvanMulawski "Completely wrong"? It started with `use escape chars...`! Even the answer doesn't mention that!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we write " in nsstring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551657/how-can-we-write-in-nsstring)

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII "Huge difference"? Being pedantic with pride...BTW, not ALL `escape sequence`s start with a `back-slash` !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString * name = [ [NSString alloc] initWithString: @" src=\" " ];
```